# Getting WM name through X11 without EWMH?

Tags: c, linux, x11, xorg, ewmh

I'm writing a program that needs to detect the name of the running Window Manager (for example, Compiz) on a Linux host running X11.

I'm currently relying on the Extended Window Manager Hints specification, which allows me to query `_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK` through `XGetWindowProperty` to get the ID of a `Window` which I can then query (through another call to `XGetWindowProperty`) for the `_NET_WM_NAME` property:

```
if ((disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
{
    if (!(XGetWindowProperty(disp, DefaultRootWindow(disp), XInternAtom(disp, "_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK", True),
        0, 1024, False, XA_WINDOW, &actual_type, &actual_format, &nitems, &bytes, (unsigned char **) &wm_check_window)))
    {
        if (!(XGetWindowProperty(disp, *wm_check_window, XInternAtom(disp, "_NET_WM_NAME", True),
            0, 1024, False, XInternAtom(disp, "UTF8_STRING", True), &actual_type,
            &actual_format, &nitems, &bytes, (unsigned char **) &wm_name)))
        {
            strncpy(str, (char *) wm_name, MAX_STRLEN);
            XFree(wm_name);
        }
    }
}
```

This works surprisingly nicely for EWMH-compliant Window Managers, but it doesn't work at all for non-compliant ones. I've tried grabbing the `WM_NAME` property on those, but that only contains the title (or something related to the title) of the active window.

Is there any way to get the actual *name* of the Window Manager through X11 *without* EWMH?

Comment: If there was a pre-EWMH way, way, why would we need the EWMH way?

Comment: Because standards overlap all the time. I was just wondering if a previous, more common, standard provided the same properties.

Comment: All the time? Well, not this time. The X philosophy once was that a program shouldn't care whether a WM is running or not. Then Motif was invented, it provided `XmIsMotifWMRunning` (check its source) and it all went downhill from there. Note, many window managers which are definitely not Motif will fool `XmIsMotifWMRunning` into reporting TRUE.